# How do I parse xml data that is stored in a variable as a string so as to obtain the values in the tags?

Tags: swift, xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse the xml data stored in a variable as a string so as to get it's values how do I do that?

the xml data is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Details>
<name>name_of_the_device</name>
<ip>ip_of_the_device</ip>
</Details>
```

Since XMLParser takes and argument of only URL, data and InputStream i was wondering if there was any way to parse xml data stored in a variable as a string. The requirement is that I cannot write this xml data to an external file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to Data

```
if let data = xmlString.data(using: .utf8) {
    let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
    ...
}
```

Comment: what if i have numbers and other data in the xml suppose I have `00231<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Details>
<name>name_of_the_device</name>
<ip>ip_of_the_device</ip>
</Details>` will it still work or do i have to remove the numbers and other junk value?

Comment: Yes, anything before the `<?xml version="1.0"...>` tag will make it an invalid xml

Comment: It works for me if i don't have the numbers but if the numbers are there then it doesn't work and gives the error `NSXMLParserErrorMessage=Document is empty`

Comment: If you have stuff in the XML that means it's not XML then you don't have XML. Parsing non-XML is an entirely different problem from parsing XML.